# How to add data from listbox1 to listbox2 in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm creating a application in angularjs where I want to add value from listbox1 to listbox2.

When I'm clicking on any li tab I'm getting value of that li but when I am trying to push the value into other listbox its not getting displayed.

Please help me ..

Thanx in advaced

link :- http://plnkr.co/edit/jZeeyFmjIlcsasyL9CzC?p=preview

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', ['ngDragDrop']);
App.controller('OverviewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list2 = [
        {'title': 'Item 1'},
        {'title': 'Item 2'},
        {'title': 'Item 7'},
        {'title': 'Item 8'}
    ];
    $scope.list1 = [
        {'title': 'Item 1'},
        {'title': 'Item 2'},
        {'title': 'Item 3'},
        {'title': 'Item 4'},
        {'title': 'Item 5'},
        {'title': 'Item 6'},
        {'title': 'Item 7'},
        {'title': 'Item 8'}
    ];
    $scope.toggle = function(test,$scope){
       // alert(test)
        $scope.list2.push($scope.list2.title.test);
    }
});
```

HTML code :-

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="OverviewCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-5" > 
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4>List 1</h4></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list1" ng-click="toggle(item.title)" >{{item.title}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  style="margin-top: 70px; margin-bottom: 10px">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right btn-sm" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
        </br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left btn-sm" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h4>List 2</h4></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="list-group">
                   <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list2" >{{item.title}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work since you are not copying the object in your list.
`list2.title` makes no sense because `list2` is an array. This would be more reasonable:

```
$scope.toggle = function(item){
    $scope.list2.push(item);
}
```

And change the way you call `toggle` to:

```
ng-click="toggle(item)"
```

On a side note I must point out that `toggle` just adds to `list2` but doesn't remove from `list1`, which is probably not the behavior you are aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the array, it is expecting an object like {'title': "something"}. But you are pushing a String into the array.

Try this.

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list1" ng-click="toggle(item)" >{{item.title}}</li>

$scope.toggle = function(item){
                $scope.list2.push(item);
            }
```